# ReactiveUI: window size when routing in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, reactiveui

In my WPF application I have two UserControls with different sizes (Height and Width) and I'm using the routing scheme from ReactiveUI to navigate between this two Views.

My problem is that the MainWindow size is not resized when load the View.

On the RoutedViewHost I don't see any property that enable the auto resize of the window from the View size.

Is there any thing I missing or the routing don't have this feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually this is not a responsibility of the ReactiveUI. In WPF the Window has a property named SizeToContent.